# macOS Terminal Process completed on any click

Tags: macos, flutter, terminal, apple-m1

My macOS terminal is showing Process completed when I type any thing. I am not able to type or do anything on terminal (This effect my Android Studio and VsCode terminal also they just open close in an second) So all issue are causing with this terminal I try every thing restore profile etc nothing is working for me.

But one thing is strange here when I restart my Mac terminal works fine but after I work on android studio or vscode with Mac terminal (Not there default terminal because they are not working) After 1 hour same happen as I say before and as in screenshot.

[image: y]

On different questions solutions was to type `/bin/bash -x` on terminal but I can't even type single character on this.

I am finding solution for this from 1 week and not able to find any thing I need to restart me laptop every 1 hour to work.

I am using BigSur with M1 processor.

Also it was working fine before but I work on Flutter so I have set path and run commands like

```
Run: nano ~/.zshrc
Add: export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
Run: source ~/.zshrc
```

And some bash commands to set path.